# Leading-edge Ruby and Gems break on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rubygems, native

I am loading a new machine with the gems I need to run Rails and talk to my databases. It appears that using the leading stable rails gem (4.2) causes numerous breakages in gems with native code (Ubuntu 14.10, GCC 4.9.1).

I've managed to drastically reduce the number of broken gems by wiping and installing rails -v 4.0.12, but I'm left with no RDBMS (database) interface gems. None of sqlite3, mysql2 or pg will compile.

Warning to all rubyists: do NOT do 'gem update' until this is resolved.

UPDATE: I started with ruby-2.1.5, same problem. When 2.2.0 was released I tried it to see if it helped. Same issue, no joy.

UPDATE2: it appears that in /usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h there's an unfulfilled #include, it's asking for ruby/config.h from within the ruby sub-directory. There is no such subdir, and there is no such file.

Here's the mkmf.log from pg-0.18.1, without all the growing stack traces:

```
    find_executable: checking for pg_config... -------------------- yes

--------------------

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql     -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Wl,-R/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L. -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L. -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lruby-static  -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
In file included from /usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:35:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1710,
                 from /usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from conftest.c:1:
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward/ruby/st.h:2:2: warning: #warning use "ruby/st.h" instead of bare "st.h" [-Wcpp]
 #warning use "ruby/st.h" instead of bare "st.h"
  ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward/ruby/st.h:6:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:35,
                 from /usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1710,
                 from /usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from conftest.c:1:
... many further stack growth failures ...

/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward/ruby/st.h:2:2: warning: #warning use "ruby/st.h" instead of bare "st.h" [-Wcpp]
 #warning use "ruby/st.h" instead of bare "st.h"
  ^
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward/ruby/st.h:6:21: error: #include nested too deeply
 #include "ruby/st.h"
                     ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1710:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from conftest.c:1:
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:504:59: error: unknown type name âst_data_tâ
 void st_foreach_safe(struct st_table *, int (*)(ANYARGS), st_data_t);
                                                           ^
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:761:1: error: unknown type name âst_index_tâ
 st_index_t rb_memhash(const void *ptr, long len);
 ^
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:762:1: error: unknown type name âst_index_tâ
 st_index_t rb_hash_start(st_index_t);
 ^
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:762:1: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:763:1: error: unknown type name âst_index_tâ
 st_index_t rb_hash_uint32(st_index_t, uint32_t);
 ^
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:763:39: error: expected â)â before âuint32_tâ
 st_index_t rb_hash_uint32(st_index_t, uint32_t);
                                       ^
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:764:1: error: unknown type name âst_index_tâ
 st_index_t rb_hash_uint(st_index_t, st_index_t);
 ^
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:764:1: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:765:1: error: unknown type name âst_index_tâ
 st_index_t rb_hash_end(st_index_t);
 ^
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:765:1: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:769:1: error: unknown type name âst_index_tâ
 st_index_t rb_str_hash(VALUE);
 ^
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:941:47: error: unknown type name âst_data_tâ
 void rb_ivar_foreach(VALUE, int (*)(ANYARGS), st_data_t);
                                               ^
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:942:1: error: unknown type name âst_index_tâ
 st_index_t rb_ivar_count(VALUE);
 ^
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who helps!

Comment: Folks, I have come to the conclusion that something has changed in Ubuntu 14.10 that our gem-builders are not taking into account. My 14.04 system works flawlessly. Unfortunately there is a bug in the Brix Pro drivers in 14.04, which is why I against my better judgement went to 14.10.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using anything like rbenv or rvm? I personally prefer rvm, but they do similar things. Check out this page:

https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.10

I don't have a 14.10 installation to play with right now, but I strongly urge against using the built-in (system) ruby, whether you're in development, production, or whatever. I always run into similar native gem issues as this, and I find that using these tools typically obviates compile problems.